# Matplotlib line plot: data point not displayed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an multi-dimensional array of 147637 rows and 175 columns. Now I want to plot only one of the column , i.e, the last column. The last column is filled with 0s in all rows except these 5 rows: 29528,  59051,  88583, 118110, 147636. These rows have a value of 1.
Below is the code that I used to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
workBoundary=-1
fig,(ax1)=plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)
ax1.plot(allPathsDistance[:,workBoundary],color='maroon')
plt.show()
```

Below is the output: [image]
Notice the x axis. According to this figure there is no '1' value between rows 0 and 60000.

But when I zoom in to the picture:
[image]

A '1' valued data point appears at roughly 30000th row as it should.(29528th row, to be exact).  I can't figure out why this is happening. Can anyone help rectify this ? I restarted the Spyder IDE but this behavior did not change.

Additional Info:

if the x axis limits are edited to not show 0 as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
workBoundary=-1
fig,(ax1)=plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)
ax1.plot(allPathsDistance[:,workBoundary],color='maroon')  

ax1.set_xlim(left=10)

plt.show()
```

then the line at 30000th row appears. result: 
[image]

This seems to suggest that the matplotlib is not plotting the data at some of the positions on the plot area.

Version info:
matplotlib: 2.1.0
Spyder: 3.1.4
Windows:7
Python: 3.6.3

Comment: This should not be a resolution problem. But I have problems replicating the issue; it seems the working and non-working code are identical? And the output seems correct for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdmOG.png

Comment: My bad. The code I copied in the additional info section was missing a statement.

Comment: The image above was produces without `set_xlim`, so it still applies.

Comment: Well I can't answer as to why you can't reproduce this. But this is the code and the problem that I actually faced. I googled the phenomenon but I couldn't find anything hence posted here.

Comment: For once, create a [mcve], i.e. a piece of code that one can copy from the question an run. The plot you show looks like you did other things before those lines shown. This ensures that we are not talking about the same thing here.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have just very sharp spikes that are sparsely distributed in your data, you can use `ax.vlines()` to make sure they are all visible:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

##setting up the data
allPathsDistance = np.zeros(147637)
allPathsDistance[[29528, 59051, 88583, 118110, 147636]] = 1.0
xvals = np.arange(allPathsDistance.shape[0])

##masking:
mask = allPathsDistance>0

##plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.vlines(xvals[mask], np.zeros_like(xvals[mask]),allPathsDistance[mask])
ax.set_xlim([xvals[0]-1000,xvals[-1]+1000])

plt.show()
```

...and here is the result:

[image: result of above code]

Hope this helps.